# Indexing a ListView object

Tags: django

I have ListView query set with with the nicknames of people called persons. I want to display the first nicknames and then loop over the rest. I am unable to find a way to index the query set, is there another way?

```
<h1>{{ persons.1.nickname }}</h1>
<h1>{{ persons.2.nickname }}</h1>
<h1>{{ persons.3.nickname }}</h1>

{{% for person in persons[3:] %}}
 <h5>{{ person.nickname }}</h5>
{{% endfor %}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this(using [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)):

```
{% for person in persons %}
   {% if forloop.counter < 4 %}
   <h1>{{ person.nickname }}</h1>
   {% else %}
   <h5>{{ person.nickname }}</h5>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) template filter.

```
{% for person in persons|slice:":3" %}
    <h5>{{ person.nickname }}</h5>
{% endfor %}
```

This approach using slice might cause more queries than in ruddra's answer - you could check using the django-debug-toolbar. In practice the extra queries might not make much difference to performance, and you should choose the approach that you think is more maintainable. If the extra queries are an issue, you could try returning a list from the list view's `get_queryset` method.